# Show images from links in Underscore templates (especially from dropbox image links)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, underscore.js

How do you insert image link into an underscore template, so that it will display the image?

Comment: Is there something that `<img src="...">` doesn't do for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
script type="text/template" class="imageViewTemplate">
      <img src=<%=imageUrl%> />
</script>
```

Then you have to interpret the template passing a url to the compiled template. For example if you are using backbone, you will do something like below in your backbone view render function.

```
render(){
      var compiledTemplate = _.template($("#imageViewTemplate").text()));
      var interpretedImageTemplate = compiledTemplate({url: "url to image service"});
      $(this.el).append( interpretedImageTemplate );
}
```

This is just to show a  dirty example how we can insert image link. Its better to have an abstract class that takes template and model which then can be reused.